# Android headache with Strings: How can I centralize all strings within my app?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, internationalization

I am writing an Android app, so I´ve got all strings on my `strings.xml` as usual and stated per Android official docs.

Until here everything is fine, but the problem comes up when I want to use a String in a Java "standard" class; i.e, let say this String in `Email.java`:

```
public static final String EMAIL_NOT_VALID = "The email address provided is not valid.";
```

You can say I can place this String on `strings.xml` and do:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.invalid_email_message)
```

The problem with this approach is that **I will be forced to pass the Android Context to every single Java object within my app, with all the mocking problems that this involves when it comes to Testing.**

**Thus, is it possible to do this without passing the Context? Or do I need to have two files (`strings.xml` and `xyz.java`) with separate strings**?

I´ve been searching for hours an answer to this question on StackOverFlow without luck)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you have a singleton which abstracts this and you call it to get the strings, leaving up to it (the singleton) to provide the context? You could then also make the singleton expose the context so that you can inject it for tests/mocking.

Comment: @ankitaggarwal Please read the question. I stated I don´t want that solution

Comment: @npinti Sounds really interesting. Could you please explain it a little bit more please?

Comment: I am not an android person, so I do not know if what I provided is actually doable. Does the application context change from one class to the next, or is it the same?

Comment: @npinti Is the same context, I think.

Comment: "I will be forced to pass the Android Context to every single Java object within my app" -- only a handful of classes in an app should be involved in presenting messages to the user. Most of those will be activities, fragments, or other aspects of your presentation layer, and they usually have easy access to the `Activity` as a `Context`. If you have background work that results in user-readable messages, your `Service` is a `Context`, etc. If you have hardcoded strings "in every single Java object", you have OO and GUI architecture issues.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don´t think I have "OO and GUI architecture issues" for having log messages for debugging inside classes, my friend. Btw, good book ;-)

Comment: "log messages for debugging" do not need to be translated, as they are not shown to users.

Comment: @CommonsWare What about messages like "Invalid email"? I am planning to only show messages from <name>Activity.java classes; what do you think about this strategy?

Comment: "What about messages like "Invalid email"?" -- that should be displayed by your UI layer (activities, fragments, etc.), in which case you have a `Context` handy for obtaining your string from a resource ID.

Comment: Ok buddy, you´re absolutely right. I see the point now. I´ll prepare the setter methods (in the specific case of the email) in order to return null if something was wrong. Do you think this is a good option? (Btw, if you write the last comment as a question I will be happy to mark it as the good answer). Many thanks for your help, my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put your strings in `assets` folder, it needs to be created in `YourProject/app/src/main/assets` inside assets you can create a new folder named i.e. "localization" and here store your localization files like `strings_en`, in this file store all your strings in a JSON object `"{"key" : "value"}` after you've done all this, you'll need to create a class which will manage all languages.

```
public class LocalizationManager {

   private static LocalizationManager mInstance = null;
   public String currentLanguage = "";
   JSONObject currentLanguageObject = new JSONObject();
   private AssetManager assetManager = BaseApplication.getInstance().getAssets(); // BaseApplication is just a class that extends Application class

   private LocalizationManager() {
   }

   public static LocalizationManager getInstance() {
       if (mInstance == null) {
           mInstance = new LocalizationManager();
       }
       return mInstance;
   }

   private boolean assetExists(String path) {
       boolean bAssetOk = false;
       try {
           InputStream stream = assetManager.open(path);
           stream.close();
           bAssetOk = true;
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return bAssetOk;
   }

   public String getLocalizedString(String string) {
       String language = BaseApplication.getInstance().getLanguage();
       if (!currentLanguage.equalsIgnoreCase(language)) {
           if (assetExists("localization/strings_" + language)) {
               InputStream input;
               try {
                   input = assetManager.open("localization/strings_" + language);
                   int size = input.available();
                   byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                   input.read(buffer);
                   input.close();
                   String responseString = new String(buffer);
                   Object json;
                   try {
                       json = new JSONTokener(responseString).nextValue();
                       if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
                           currentLanguageObject = (JSONObject) json;
                           currentLanguage = language;
                           return currentLanguageObject.optString(string, string);
                       }
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       return string;
                   }
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   return string;
               }
           }
       } else {
           return currentLanguageObject.optString(string, string);
       }
       return string;
   }
}
```

Then in any class you can just call `LocalizationManager.getInstance().getLocalizedString("Your string key")`. With this approach you will need to add a "change language" option within your application, store the value as `en` for example in preferences and the language will be changed dynamically. Here is how I did it:

```
public void setLanguage(String language) {
    mPreferences = getSharedPreferences(LANGUAGE_KEY_FOR_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Language", language);
    editor.apply();
    mListener.onLanguageChanged();
}


public String getLanguage() {
    mPreferences = getSharedPreferences(LANGUAGE_KEY_FOR_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return mPreferences.getString("Language", "en");
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! That was the strategy I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Don't hold your Strings, especially messages in your code classes. Never. You can not translate it to other languages then. Use string resources for everything, maybe except some logmessages you see only in the debugger.

You could create a class like Globals.java and put there a

```
public static Context appContext;
```

and you fill this static on appStart (= "onCreate" of your MainActivity) with

```
Globals.appContext = getApplicationContext();
```

and then you have a Context everywhere.
Just make sure, you refresh the context in the onResume event of your MainActivity when you come back from background.

You see this "Problem" with the context throughout the entire Android API - SQLiteOpenHelper needs a context... *everything* needs a context. It's part of the game in Android.

Comment: Very nice answer my friend, thanks for it. I am going to give it a go. Besides, I am planning to only show messages from <name>Activity.java classes; what do you think about this strategy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.somecommonstuff)
```

... everywhere in your application, even in static constants declarations. Unfortunately, it supports the system resources only.

From one of the threads in stack overflow

Comment: It´s not working as I´d like to. That line will return an int, while I need the proper String. As well, it´s not detecting the strings I´ve got in strings.xml